# How to Change text in NSLocationUsageDescription

Tags: ios, privacy

HI all I am currently trying to change the text in NSLocationUsageDescription.
Currently it says: MyAPP "would like to use your current location"

I would like to change the text **"would like to use your current location"**

Does anyone have the steps to do this?

Currently In the plist I have custom text in the string value field but it doesn't change  **"would like to use your current location"**

Any help greatly appreciated.!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(For iOS 6 +.)  In the info.plist add the key "Privacy - Location Usage Description" the Type is String and in Value add the text you want to appear when the user is prompted to enable Location Services for your app.

Hava a look at the Apple Property List Key Reference for more info: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html